# Group line categories based on similar text from .dat file into a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, csv

I am completely new to using CSV. I have seen answers based on line by line, but I cold not find reading groups of lines. I have a csv file containing for example the following data format below, where the first line contains starting, month and day. From the second line I have data only on the last two columns say A and B.

```
starting    6   3
    34.75   15
    34.75   15.25
    32.5    14.2
starting    7   27
    12.75   14.75
    13  15  
starting    7   28
    29  33
    29  33.25
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the data from below each **starting** and write them separately as a list of 3 arrays with 2 columns each. The purpose for this is to be able to plot each array of **starting** independently.

Here is the code I managed to write after several search, please kindly help to correct me where I am missing it.

```
import numpy as np

#input file
f=open('./latlon.dat','r') 

lines = f.readlines()    # Read file and close
f.close()

i = 0
tr = []

while (i < (len(lines)-1) ):
    line = lines[i]
    i = i+1
    linesplit = line.strip().split('\t')
    if linesplit[0] == 'start' :
        latlog = int(linesplit[1])
        latlogarray = np.genfromtxt(lines[i:(i+latlog)])
        for k in range (i-1,i+latlog):
            i = i+latlogarray
            tr.append(k)
print(tr)
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Python's CSV module.

Reading your problem, you have a *group* which is delimited by a line with `starting`.  The data for the group starts after that line.  Finally, you want all groups.

If that's true, then you want to read line-by-line, and when you read a line with `starting` in the first column, save the last group (if it exists) and start a new group:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import pprint

groups = []
group = None
with open('latlon.dat', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')

    for row in reader:
        # Normalize all cells at once
        row = [cell.strip() for cell in row]

        # Deal with "blank" lines
        if len(row) == 0 or len(row) == 1:
            continue

        # Starting new group...
        if row[0] == 'starting':
            # Save last group, if it exists
            if group:
                groups.append(group)
            # Reset group
            group = []
            # Don't do anything else with this row
            continue

        # A "data row"
        group.append([float(row[1]), float(row[2])])


groups.append(group)
pprint.pprint(groups)
```

When I run that against your sample, I get:

```py
[
 [[34.75, 15.0], [34.75, 15.25], [32.5, 14.2]],
 [[12.75, 14.75], [13.0, 15.0]],
 [[29.0, 33.0], [29.0, 33.25]]
]
```

Comment: Hmm, a couple of things.  I just updated your example, by adding a code fence around it... and when I copy-paste everything in that code fence as use that as **latlon.dat**, it runs and gives me that output. So, please do the same—use your sample as-is from the post and test my code with that as the input.

Comment: Also, how many groups are in your actual data?  I presume it's more than the three in your sample.

Comment: your answer is exactly what I expect. I have about 8 groups in some cases and even more in others. I could have shared the file here but I don't know how to do that. I am new to StackOverflow. Can you guide me, then I can share the file?

Comment: So, when you run my code against the sample in your post, it works? If so, then there's something in your real data that's not shown in your sample. You'll need to find where the problem in your real data is. And either fix it by hand, or adjust the code handle this new condition.  Either way, it sounds like my code works for the sample you posted. Please accept and/or upvote my contribution.

Comment: When I ran your code with the sample data you used, I got the following error:                                   AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-e4202efe330b> in <module>
     27 
     28         # A "data row"
---> 29         group.append([float(row[1]), float(row[2])])
     30 
     31 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'.                                                            However, I have also edited the code to look close to what it should look like.

Comment: Oh, there aren't pipes, well, that changes things. :) I went back and looked at your sample data, and your sample code, and I'm guessing your file is actually tab-delimited. So, I changed all the spaces between values to a tab. It may look weird, but I think that's what your data actually is. I also updated my code, `delimiter='\t'`, so it should now parse a purely tab-delimited file. Try now.

Comment: now it works. I am marking your answer after making some check on my file and changing the delimiter to ', '

Comment: Oh, so it is ***comma*** separated? Okay. In the future, when asking for help processing data, please copy-paste the data *exactly* as is. It'll make solving the problem a lot quicker, and less frustrating for all :) Cheers!

Comment: Sure! Today is my first attempt on StackOverflow. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad we were successful.

Comment: yea,you made it possible. you deserve an award

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to work with pandas in this case:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./latlon.dat', sep = ' ') # sep is whatever delimiter you want
df.plot() # will plot the three variables together
```